# iphone application crashes frequently with memory warning

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks, bitmapimage

I am developing an application for ipad which is dealing with image views, bitmap context, creating image from bitmap contet, video player, audio player, recording,picker views, table views and so on. The application is crashing with memory warning after some time. I am getting that the application exited with signal 9. But it is not entering in did receive memory warning delegate. then how can i know that it is recieving a memory warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How To Debug Memory Leaks with XCode and Instruments Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks Alex!. Great link. Learned something tonight.